# Using an AngularJS controller's scope in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, scope, typescript

*The situation*: 
I recently started using Typescript and am currently integrating it into my AngularJS web application. I have been using the 'controller as' syntax instead of $scope where possible.

*The issue*: I can't seem to find a proper way to replace `var self = this;`
I started replacing `vm` with `this` everywhere which soon got me to a dead-end when inside of forEach functions, click events etc.

*My temporary solution*: casting `var self = this;` in each function, since I can't cast it globally as far as I understand. It also doesn't work in all cases.

*My question*: have I missed something obvious? Is there a better way to access the controller's scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fat Arrow functions to the rescue!!!**

There is really no need to use `var self = this` in TypeScript...

Fat arrow functions preserve the (lexical) scope (meaning of this) inside of callback functions:

```
var self = this;
fooService.doSomething()
  .then(result => {
    console.assert(this === self);  // this is valid and true
  });
```

For your specific example:

```
items.forEach((item) => {
  this.somethingElse = item; // (no need for self)
});
```

**Note** This is not really a feature of TypeScript, but more so a function of ES6/ES2015

[Further Explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this)

Comment: So this is what those fat arrows do... it was something obvious after all. Thanks a bunch!